# List circulation in Python for Project Euler 37

Tags: python, list

So, I was doing [Project Euler 37](http://projecteuler.net/problem=37)

I need to circulate a list

input:            2345  # converted to list inside function

expected output:  [[3,4,5,2],[4,5,2,3],[5,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]

Here is my function for that

```
def circulate(n):           #2345
    lst=list(str(n))          #[2,3,4,5]
    res=[]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        temp=lst.pop(0)
        lst.append(temp)
        print lst             #print expected list 
        res.append(lst)       #but doesn't append as expected
    return res
print circulate(2345)
```

My output is:

```
['3', '4', '5', '2']
['4', '5', '2', '3']
['5', '2', '3', '4']
['2', '3', '4', '5']
[['2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '4', '5']]
```

The function prints lst correct every time, but doesn't append as expected.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append *copies* of your list to `res`:

```
res.append(lst[:])
```

You were appending a reference to the list being altered instead; all references reflect the changes made to the one object.

You may want to look at [`collections.deque()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead; this double-ended list object supports efficient rotation with a `.rotate()` method:

```
from collections import deque

def circulate(n):
    lst = deque(str(n))
    res = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst.rotate(1)
        res.append(list(lst))
    return res
```

Comment: Thank you. That made it. When I visualized the code above on http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display I was wondering why it references to the old unmodified list instead of modified.

Comment: Yes, Pythontutor.com is great for showing you what happens.